# Manage authentication of different types of users in express.js using passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am having problem managing the states of different types of users using Passport.js in Express.js 4.x.

I have 3 kinds user collections in my mongodb database

```
1. Member (has his own profile page)
2. Operator (has his own dashboard)
3. Admin (handles the backend)
```

I have created their separate Login/Registration systems. But only member seems to work, and the others don't. I have even written different sets of login/registration strategies for each user.
Like for the member passport.use('signup') and passport.use('login').
for operator passport.use('op-signup') and passport.use('op-login') and so on.
What I think is that I am not using the correct approach for handling users, means the collections don't need to be separated but role based in a single collection. Right ?

Here is the current mongoose models I have right now;

```
// Member Schema
var MemberSchema = new Schema({
   username: String,
   password: String,
   name: { first: String, last: String },
   locality: String,
   // and other attributes
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Member', MemberSchema);

// OperatorSchema
var OperatorSchema = new Schema({
   username: String,
   password: String,
   name: { first: String, last: String },
   officeAddress: String,
   privatePhone: Number,
   // and other attributes related to the operator
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Operator', OperatorSchema);
```

Is the above approach correct or like this ?

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
   username: String,
   password: String,
   roles: {
       member: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Member' },
       operator: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Operator' },
       admin: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Admin' }
   }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// and then plug the sub models to this parent one

// Member Schema
var MemberSchema = new Schema({
   _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   name: { first: String, last: String },
   locality: String,
   // and other attributes
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Member', MemberSchema);

// OperatorSchema
var OperatorSchema = new Schema({
   _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   name: { first: String, last: String },
   officeAddress: String,
   privatePhone: Number,
   // and other attributes related to the operator
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Operator', OperatorSchema);
```

I am quite confused here and in a stuck situation, because when a user state is managed in session after login, the user object is exposed to the request object, and so it can only handle one type of user at a time, and may be member, operator and admin can't log in at the same time from the same browser.

So how do I manage all of these user as different instances in the browser ?
I am quite a newbie in Node.js and coming from a PHP background where managing user states was a breeze :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i would do is to add plugins, because you are duplicating username and password field, it is very redundant

models/plugins/member.js

```
module.exports = function(schema) {
  schema.add({
      // All the appropriate fields that your member schema need
      role: String,

   });

}
```

models/user.js

```
var member = require(./plugins/member);

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     username: String,
     password: String
});

UserSchema.plugins(member);
```

Later on when you want to check which user could access to which route, use middleware to check it

create this in your passport configuration

```
exports.requireRole = function(role) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.user && req.user.role === role) next();
      else
          res.send(404);
    }
}
```

In your route later

```
app.get('/profile', requireRole('member'), function(req, res) {
  // do whatever you want to do
});

app.get('/dashbord', requireRole('operator'), function(req, res) {
  // do whatever you want to do
});
```

There are a lot of ways to implement different access level to a user. This method is one of many.

Comment: The solution is a bit drag for me as I am from Laravel background, but thanks! It did the trick. I will try to improve and modularize the technique in some near future to avoid any further conflicts between users.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use schema inhertiance. That is why we use an ORM like mongoose.

```
var VehicleSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
  make : String,
}, { collection : 'vehicles', discriminatorKey : '_type' });

var CarSchema = VehicleSchema.extend({
  year : Number
});
var BusSchema = VehicleSchema.extend({
  route : Number
})

var Vehicle = mongoose.model('vehicle', VehicleSchema),
    Car = mongoose.model('car', CarSchema),
    Bus = mongoose.model('bus', BusSchema);

var accord = new Car({ 
  make : 'Honda',
  year : 1999
});
var muni = new Bus({
  make : 'Neoplan',
  route : 33
});

accord.save(function(err) {
  muni.save(function(err) {
    // vehicles are saved with the _type key set to 'car' and 'bus'
  });
})
```

At this point in MongoDB you will have documents similar to this

```
{ "_type" : "car", "make" : "Honda", "year" : 1999, "_id" : ObjectId("5024460368368a3007000002"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_type" : "bus", "make" : "Neoplan", "route" : 33, "_id" : ObjectId("5024460368368a3007000003"), "__v" : 0 }
Source
```

when querying

```
Vehicle.find({}, function(err, vehicles) {
  console.log(vehicles[0]); // vehicles[0] instanceof Car === true
  console.log(vehicles[1]); // vehicles[1] instanceof Bus === true
});
```

Checkout source / more examples by looking at briankircho little cheatsheet [enter link description here](https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend)